# In a Javascript key value object, how to remove quotes from value

Tags: javascript, json, key-value

From a remote db, I retrieve the schema of a table and get a a JSON object of the following form:

```
{ Id:                 
   { type: 'INT',          
     allowNull: false,     
     defaultValue: null,   
     primaryKey: false },  
  Prefix:                    
   { type: 'NVARCHAR',     
     allowNull: true,      
     defaultValue: null,   
     primaryKey: false },  
  FirstName:               
   { type: 'NVARCHAR',     
     allowNull: true,      
     defaultValue: null,   
     primaryKey: false },  
  Assets:               
   { type: 'INT',          
     allowNull: false,     
     defaultValue: null,   
     primaryKey: false },  
  Role:          
   { type: 'NVARCHAR',     
     allowNull: true,      
     defaultValue: null,   
     primaryKey: false },  
}
```

I want to transform the `type` of every column (Id, Prefix, FirstName, Assets, Role in this example) to something in the form `DataTypes.INTEGER` or `DataTypes.STRING` so at the end we get:

```
 { Id:                 
   { type: DataTypes.INTEGER,          
     allowNull: false,     
     defaultValue: null,   
     primaryKey: false },  
  Prefix:                    
   { type: DataTypes.STRING,     
     allowNull: true,      
     defaultValue: null,   
     primaryKey: false },  
  FirstName:               
   { type: DataTypes.STRING,     
     allowNull: true,      
     defaultValue: null,   
     primaryKey: false },  
  Assets:               
   { type: DataTypes.INTEGER,          
     allowNull: false,     
     defaultValue: null,   
     primaryKey: false },  
  Role:          
   { type: DataTypes.STRING,     
     allowNull: true,      
     defaultValue: null,   
     primaryKey: false },  
}
```

Please note the difference, the `type` value is no longer a string.

Initially i was trying the following:

```
var DataTypes = {
    NVARCHAR: 'STRING',
    INT: 'INTEGER',
    VARCHAR: 'STRING',
    DATETIME: 'DATE',
    FLOAT: 'FLOAT',
    NCHAR: 'STRING'
}

Object.keys(schema).forEach(function(fieldName) {
        types[schema[fieldName]['type']] ? schema[fieldName]['type'] = 'DataTypes.'+types[schema[fieldName]['type']] : console.log('Could not find type: ' + schema[fieldName]['type'])
    })
```

but then I would get `"DataTypes.STRING"` instead of `DataTypes.STRING`

Comment: Where is `DataTypes.STRING` defined? Do you mean `DataTypes.NVARCHAR`? Or are you expecting `type: "STRING"`?

Comment: *`type: DataTypes.INTEGER`* is not valid JSON. You'd need to stick with `type: 'INT'`, but then you can compare that with `DataTypes.INTEGER`, as in `if (schema.Id.type === DataTypes.INTEGER)`.

Comment: I am getting the original table definition from a remote db and then I want to transform the json received into a new file which will serve as model for an app. This new JS object will be included in a function like this [one](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/user.js)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the link you have mentioned in your comment which is [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html#static-variable-DataTypes), but a quick look at their documentation shows this is how you define a new model:

```
const WhateverYouWant = sequelize.define('whatever', {
  Id : { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, 
         defaultValue: null, primaryKey: false},

  // other columns you have...
});
```

Looking at that example, it seems `DataTypes` is an object and `INTEGER` is property within their library. So if you reference their library, then you will be able to use those types.

Comment: I know that `DataTypes` is an object and `Integer` a property, what I am asking is the function which helps me to transform the JS object into the second version so `"INT"` becomes `DataTypes.STRING`, the latter without quotes, so it's not taken as a string.

Comment: @bondifrench Yes and I am saying you need their framework to do it. It's not JSON that you can create and pass it to them, it's code (object and property). Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really, I am trying to create the file that will be consumed by `Sequelize` so I can interact with the db, you are implying that `Sequelize` creates this file, it does not.
I want to create the type of file that I linked to, in order to do that, I need to transform the data structure received into the one I mentioned. There is actually a [module](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) that exists that does what I am describing but in a raw way, by concatenating text, my question is: is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: @bondifrench I looked at the link and i do not think there is any other way except for raw text. Having said that you should interact to see if sequelize works with JSON format or some other well known format. It would be very odd if it only works with text.

Comment: @bondifrench and I am not implying sequelize creates the files. I am saying it is sequelize code and not an data exchange format. If you import their library then you can use those types.

Comment: That's not what I am asking, I know how to use Sequelize and it does not matter if it's for Sequelize or not, my question is specifically on data transformation, can I transform the first data structure without having to use raw text? It seems not apparently.